# Max value for column range

Tags: vba, excel

Needing some help to determine the max value for the column range. Should be easy enough but my column range is determined by a string which is used to calculate the total number of existing rows on the sheet.

I have tried the methods in my code below but just getting `#NAME?` returned in the specified cells.

Thanks

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("API-VAL")
LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).row ' Determins the last row from previous populated calulation
.Range("BW1").Value = "=worksheetfunction.Max(BU1:BU & LastRow)"
.Range("BX1").Formula = "=Max(BU1:BU & CStr(LastRow))"
.Range("BY1").Formula = "=Min(BU1:BU & LastRow)"
End With
```

Comment: If you are just using formulas, in BW1 then,`=MAX(BU:BU)` will always have the answer..

Comment: You're getting `#NAME?` because you're trying to put VBA code in an Excel cell. Excel doesn't interpret VBA. That `.Value =` assignment should be assigning to a VBA expression, not to a VBA string literal. Remove the quotes and the equal sign. Works? Also, why the explicit `CStr` conversion in one place but not in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove LastRow (does it need a dot in that line?) from inside the quotes as the "worksheet" won't know what that means.

```
.Range("BW1").Formula = "=Max(BU1:BU" & LastRow & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this format if you do not want the equation pasted in the cell. This will just give you the value in cell

```
.Range("BW1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("BU1:BU" & LastRow))
.Range("BY1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("Bu1:BU" & LastRow))
```